# C# ServiceDescriptionImporter NoCodeGenerated i cant find the issue

Tags: c#, dynamic, wsdl, service-reference

Hey there im am running into a situation with the ServiceDescription importer.

In the code (which is pasted below) i am trying to import and compile a service reference from a WSDL file (stored locally) sadly due to customer implications i am not allowed to share this wsdl file.

However all the code runs trough well however the following line:

```
ServiceDescriptionImportWarnings warnings = importer.Import(nm, unit);
```

constantly keeps returning: ServiceDescriptionImportWarnings.NoCodeGenerated

could someone tell me if and where i am going wrong with this code ?

```
public string[] GenerateProxyAssembly(string pathOrURL)
{
    Stream stream = File.OpenRead(pathOrURL);
    ServiceDescription desc = ServiceDescription.Read(stream);

    //find out the number of operations exposed by the web service
    //store the name of the operations inside the string array
    //iterating only through the first binding exposed as
    //the rest of the bindings will have the same number

    int i = 0;
    Binding binding = desc.Bindings[0];
    OperationBindingCollection opColl = binding.Operations;
    string[] listOfOperations = new string[opColl.Count];

    foreach (OperationBinding operation in opColl)
    {
        listOfOperations[i++] = operation.Name;
    }

    //initializing a ServiceDescriptionImporter object
    ServiceDescriptionImporter importer = new ServiceDescriptionImporter();

    //set the protocol to SOAP 1.1
    importer.ProtocolName = "Soap12";

    //setting the Style to Client in order to generate client proxy code
    importer.Style = ServiceDescriptionImportStyle.Client;

    //adding the ServiceDescription to the Importer object
    importer.AddServiceDescription(desc, null, null);
    importer.CodeGenerationOptions = CodeGenerationOptions.GenerateNewAsync;

    //Initialize the CODE DOM tree in which we will import the 
    //ServiceDescriptionImporter
    CodeNamespace nm = new CodeNamespace("test");
    CodeCompileUnit unit = new CodeCompileUnit();
    unit.Namespaces.Add(nm);

    //generating the client proxy code
    ServiceDescriptionImportWarnings warnings = importer.Import(nm, unit);

    if (warnings == 0)
    {
        //set the CodeDOMProvider to C# to generate the code in C#
        System.IO.StringWriter sw = new System.IO.StringWriter();
        CodeDomProvider provider = CodeDomProvider.CreateProvider("CSharp");
        provider.GenerateCodeFromCompileUnit(unit, sw, new CodeGeneratorOptions());

        //creating TempFileCollection
        //the path of the temp folder is hardcoded
        TempFileCollection coll = new TempFileCollection(@"C:\wmpub\tempFiles");
        coll.KeepFiles = false;

        //setting the CompilerParameters for the temporary assembly
        string[] refAssembly = { "System.dll", "System.Data.dll",
                                         "System.Web.Services.dll", "System.Xml.dll" };
        CompilerParameters param = new CompilerParameters(refAssembly);
        param.GenerateInMemory = true;
        param.TreatWarningsAsErrors = false;
        param.OutputAssembly = "WebServiceReflector.dll";
        param.TempFiles = coll;

        //compile the generated code into an assembly
        //CompilerResults results = provider.CompileAssemblyFromDom(param, unitArr);
        CompilerResults results = provider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(param, sw.ToString());
        this.assem = results.CompiledAssembly;
    }

    //return the list of operations exposed by the web service
    return listOfOperations;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't share enough information, but i'll try to anwser.

Protocol could be the issue, i had similar problem, removing this line solved the problem

```
importer.ProtocolName = "Soap12";
```

So in my case, i was trying to connect to Soap 1.1 service with wrong protocol setting.
Soap 1.1 is default value.

Please check documentation:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.services.description.servicedescriptionimporter.protocolname?view=netframework-4.8